# iscsi discovery issue

Tags: linux, iscsi

I have setup an iSCSI server on CentOS 7 and client is also CentOS 7.
I have successfully created a lun and also accessed it on client machine.
Now when I create a new lun to be shared with same client, even if do

```
# systemctl restart iscsid
```

it is not able to view the new lun which was shared from target server, it is only visible only after a reboot of the client machine.

Does anyone know a better solution?

**Update**:

I was able to resolve this issue through a `echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan` . Now I have problem, when the client reboots the login lus disappears and I have to manually login again. How can we make this permanent?